# Self similar process

Tags: stochastic-processes

I am learning long memory process and came cross the definition of self similar. By definition, process $X(t)$ is self similar if $X(at)=_d a^H X(t)$,$a>0$ and $H$ is Hurst exponent. By equality of all finite dimensional distributios, does this implied the left hand side and the right hand side of the equality have the same distribution?

Furthermore, I wonder if we can estimate H by the total variation approach? For example: if $X(t)$ is Brownian motion and we define $a=t_{i}-t_{i-1}$ and assume that interval $[0,1]$ is equally partitioned. We can show that:
$$\sqrt{a}\sum_1^n |B(t_i)-B(t_{i-1})|\to \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}$$
This gives us $H=0.5$ (which is correct for case of Brownian motion). Thus, I came up with algorithm to estimate $H$ as follow:

- With different value of $a$, calculate corresponding value of total
  variation.
- Running regression of $log(total variation)$ against    $log(a)$ to
  find exponent of $a$, which I think is $H$.

I ran 10000 simulations with Brownian motion of length 10000 and the    mean of $a$ is 0.50 and $var=0.01$. I wonder if my understanding about Hurst exponent as the exponent of a in this case is correct?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: @ Ocean : your first question doesn't quite make sense because your similarity equality is already an equality in distribution. What is it that is not clear from that ? You don't need to say that there equality in fdd (by the way it is false that if you have equality in law at every time then you have fdd equality). Best regards

Comment: @ TheBridge: thanks for your response. I think when I read the material, I got confused between equality in law of random variable and equality of all fdd.